# Group a datetime by date - without time

Tags: sql, group-by

Today I noticed, I may designed a table wrong - with lots of records ~1kk.
My goal is to group these records by `day (YYYY-mm-dd)`, but I only have a `datetime (YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s)` field.

Current query

```
SELECT COUNT(datetime), datetime FROM slowExecution group by datetime;
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: do you want count the records and group by day wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, with the `date()` function in sql which extracts the date from datetime so
`SELECT COUNT(datetime), datetime FROM slowExecution group by DATE(datetime);`